# What does CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash) do, and how to replicate it in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, cryptography, sha256, hmac

Basically, I want to replicate the following javascript code in java:

```
let h = calculateHmac(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash), key);
const calculateHmac = (seed, salt) => {  
  const hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(seed, salt);
  return hmac;
}
```

Here's my Java code so far:

```
public static String encode(String key, String hash) throws Exception {
      Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
      SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
      sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

      return bytesToHex(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(hash.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
```

My java code correctly gets the hmac, but my result is different from the js due to the `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash)` part (I'm using just `hash` in java). What does `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash)` actually do? When I print it, it seems to print the same as just `hash`. And how do I replicate that line in java?

For reference, I'm using the key `0000000000000000004d6ec16dafe9d8370958664c1dc422f452892264c59526` and hash `71b12b1ee6aad3763a3f844bec2512e6985f727de60224237552df77aa2d1d12`. When I run it through an online hmac generator tool (for example https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) I get `2d1044151d96fadd070261880e6564f7a52a33af293b57cc40fb75e099d1e232` as the output, which my java code correctly does, but is different from the js code because of the `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash)` line. Please let me know what I'm missing.

EDIT: edited for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that hash-value in JS is a String var we do need a way to get a byte[] out of it. The simple way of

```
byte[] hashValue = hash.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

does not work as we need the value and not the ASCII-code of the characters. Simply use the hexStringToByteArray method to
transform a hex-string representation to a byte array ("bytesToHex" is a service method to print out the byte array):

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class ParseHexstring {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497931/what-does-cryptojs-enc-hex-parsehash-do-and-how-to-replicate-it-in-java");
        String hash = "124d45ff6789ac01234543789012";
        byte[] hashGetBytes = hash.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] hashValue = hexStringToByteArray(hash);
        System.out.println("hash String : " + hash);
        System.out.println("hashGetBytes: " + bytesToHex(hashGetBytes));
        System.out.println("hashValue   : " + bytesToHex(hashValue));
    }
    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(s.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

That the output:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62497931/what-does-cryptojs-enc-hex-parsehash-do-and-how-to-replicate-it-in-java
hash String : 124d45ff6789ac01234543789012
hashGetBytes: 31323464343566663637383961633031323334353433373839303132
hashValue   : 124d45ff6789ac01234543789012
```